# How do I fix this link error - Undefined control sequence?

Tags: links, hyperlink

```
\header{Research  Projects}
{\textbf{Analysis of XYZ}}  \\ {\href{http://www.overleaf.com}{Something Linky}}\\
```

I am not sure what's wrong with the code, I copied the href line from the official guide and it does not get embedded and throws the error: undefined control sequence

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, refer full error message. What control sequence is undefined?

Comment: @wipet Added screenshot

Comment: Look to the log file. Your GUI is bad designed and it doesn't show the important information about this error message. The important information is what control sequence is undefined.

Comment: @wipet Please check the 2nd image. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. // Please show your preamble. Use the code tag, no screenshot for this purpose.

Comment: In order to have `\href` available, you need `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: You can see the end of the first line after the message "undefined control sequence". The end of this line shows where the problem is. The undefined control sequence is `\href`. Did you define it? No. Define it some macro file? Maybe. But such macro file isn't loaded to your document.

Comment: @egreg thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: @egreg Now the link appears as a weird box instead: https://imgur.com/a/w6PRhVN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have forgotten to load some package before your `\begin{document}`

Which part of your code causes the error ? Separate it in two lines to better understand the error message:

```
\header{Research  Projects}{\textbf{Analysis of XYZ}}  \\ 
{\href{http://www.overleaf.com}{Something Linky}}\\
```

If it is the `\header{...` line, it may be because \header is not defined in any package you use. Add a `\usepackage{...}` command in your preamble to load a package defining a \header command.

If the error comes from the second line, add for instance `\usepackage{hyperref}` towards the end of your preamble.

Edit: hyperref has a lot of options. You can use for instance

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
```

Comment: The undefined command is at the end of the first line of the error message.  In this case, it's `\href`.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thanks. I don't really know how to read the error messages: I use kile and they are often unclear to me, maybe truncated or differently formatted, so I don't often really try...

Comment: Now the link appears as a weird box instead: imgur.com/a/w6PRhVN

Comment: hyperref has a lot of options. Use for instance \usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}.

Comment: Today I learned, thanks @dominique